# Maven project uploads to Google Code 'Downloads' tab

Tags: maven, google-code

**Note: I am not asking how to use Google Code's SVN repo as a Maven repo :-)**

I'm looking for the simplest / most reliable way to automate uploading the built artifacts of a Maven project to a Google Code 'Downloads' tab.

I've found 4 different Google Code Maven plugins that claim to do this, but would appreciate any advice on evaluating them as fit-for-purpose, because they all seem to be in various states of inactivity.

1. [maven-googlecode-plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-googlecode-plugin) (Last commit: Sept 2009. Latest version: 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT)
2. [gcupload-maven-plugin](http://code.google.com/p/gcupload-maven-plugin) (Last commit: Jan 2009. Latest version: 0.9)
3. [maven-gcu-plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-gcu-plugin) (Last commit: Oct 2010. Latest version: 1.1)
4. [maven-googlecode](http://code.google.com/p/maven-googlecode) (Last commit: Feb 2008. Latest version: 2.0, but labelled 'test')

In addition to these 'level of activity' clues, some of them offer their releases on the 'Downloads' tabs, which might be a good sign from an 'eat your own dogfood' viewpoint; but as these are supposed to be Maven plugins, having them available in Maven Central might inspire more confidence.

Anyone care to comment (perhaps even the owners / committers of these projects) ?

Thanks!

---

**Update:**

I have test-driven each one of these in turn and could not get any of them to work as advertised.

Two of them are still configured to upload to a Google Code URL ending in /files, whilst another claimed to work and reported success, but the artifacts did not appear in the 'Downloads' tab. With the last one there appeared to be no released code which could be referenced as a Maven plugin.

I have since emailed each of the project committers to see what can be done.

Comment: +1 for doing an investigation of options first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not averse to looking beyond maven plugins, google code has a [SciptedUploads](http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/ScriptedUploads) documentation, which seems to provide a python script and an ant task for doing this.

You may want to start reading the comments bottoms-up to see challenges using them, if any.

I got to this page by clicking on the link to "Create a New Download" for my google code project and clicking on the "Tip".

Comment: This is an excellent response! Thank you for informing me of this. I will take a good look at this code over the next few days: at the best, a Maven plugin could directly wrap this code; at the worst, it can provide guidance on implementation detail of a Maven plugin. And in all situations, a Maven project could be configured to use maven-ant-plugin to execute the 'gcupload' task. As such, I think it is appropriate to accept this answer as the most practical in the given situation.

Answer (score 0):

I always wondered why google didn't offer a Maven repository for each project by default.

Digging further, I discovered the following deprecated project:

- http://code.google.com/p/google-maven-repository/

It appears the [recommendation](http://code.google.com/p/google-maven-repository/wiki/WhereIsMyFavoriteGoogleProject) is to publish releases to Maven Central. This makes a lot of sense, as it certainly simplifies the discovery and integration of your project with other open source.

This movement towards Maven Central is a welcome and increasing trend in Java projects. Large projects like [Oracle](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2011/08/java-net-moves-to-central/),  [Spring](http://blog.springsource.org/2009/12/02/obtaining-spring-3-artifacts-with-maven/) and [JBoss](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2011/09/8942/) are now publishing their releases there.

Comment: I absolutely agree with that. I have in fact, published by own Google Code project to Maven Central via oss.sonatype.org. It's actually very easy to follow the usage guide here: https://docs.sonatype.org/display/Repository/Sonatype+OSS+Maven+Repository+Usage+Guide

But sometimes people still want to manually download from the 'Downloads' tab, which is specifically what I was referring to. It would be nice if Maven could upload artifacts to there at the same time as a release or deploy is run.

Comment: Point taken. In fact it would be better if the downloads page could just use a link to Maven Central. Is there a support page for Google code?

Comment: That's a very good idea, although I think it should aim to be a useful convenience, rather than a restriction. For my project, I have uploaded a Maven plugin to Maven Central, and then I also have an "example of use" project source artifact which I thought shouldn't go into Maven Central, but which should be available for manual download. (I guess punters could do an anonymous svn checkout of the example project, but some people may still prefer to download a project-src.tar.gz, etc)

Comment: I have added a support issue! http://code.google.com/p/support/issues/detail?id=28249